# IIF Statement Not Returning a Value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I'm very confused by this situation, i've written quite a few IIF statements and always get them to work.  I have two columns in my dataset called CATEGORY and PCT, what i'm trying to do is return the PCT value for only one specific value in CATEGORY.

For example, I have the following table of data

```
Category    PCT
A           .50
B           .75
```

I have placed a textbox on my report and have written the following expression to return the PCT value if Category = B, like so:

```
=IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "B", Fields!PCT.Value, " ")
```

For some reason this expression returns empty every single time.  When I just put Fields!Category.Value in the textbox as a test then the value A returns which is as expected.

I'm really thrown-off by this and I know i'm missing something very simple - can someone help?

Comment: You have multiple rows of data and you say that you added a textbox on the report. Is your textbox containing this expression inside of a table or list? There is nothing wrong with your expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its important that we understand the context of the textbox as the expression seems valid.

If you placed a single textbox on your report and used your above expression (with references to the datasets) ONLY the first row of your dataset will be evaluated. In which case the expression will always evaluate to the same result.

Can you confirm that the control you are using is indeed a textbox? If it is then i believe you do need a reference to the dataset and  the expression will look more like this:

=iif(First(Fields!Category.Value, "datasetName") = "B", First(Fields!PCT.Value, "datasetName"), " ")

This would only evaluate the first row in your dataset.

If you were to do this in a tablix using your original expression then it should work.

Comment: I didn't refer to the dataset name, a very rookie mistake.  Going too fast I guess.  Thanks for the replies.